# How to specify where the application should run when failover in Marathon

Tags: mesos, failover, marathon

I'm using Mesos and Marathon. I created an application on Marathon.
When applications failover to other node in cluster, can we control where they should invoke?
I tried with LIKE "Constrains" in Marathon but it doesn't work as my expectation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why doesn't it work for you? You can do something like `type:LIKE:my_instance_type` to ensure your task runs on the same instance type if fails for any reason

Comment: For example: 
I have 4 nodes. I want my app to run on node3 if it fails. What is the constrains in this case?

Comment: Why would you want your app to run on a specific host? And what happens if that host fails as well?

Comment: that is my problem. when a failure occurs, I want to specify the host that app will run on (instead of leaving Marathon do by itself). is there any solution for that? (by using Marathon or other Mesos frameworks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LIKE or UNLIKE constraint (or set of contraints) to restrict where marathon can place any given app instance; however, you can't choose a specific one upon failure.